# What happened to CrossVersion.fullMapped in sbt 1.x (or specifically 1.2.8)?

Tags: scala, sbt

In fact, I don't see any of the x`Mapped` functions in the new release of the [librarymanagement repository](https://github.com/sbt/librarymanagement/blob/develop/core/src/main/scala/sbt/librarymanagement/CrossVersion.scala).

I get this error:

```
build.sbt:84: error: value fullMapped is not a member of object sbt.librarymanagement.CrossVersion
    "org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.1" cross CrossVersion.fullMapped{
```

for the following usage:

```
  ,addCompilerPlugin( // For circe generic:
    "org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.1" cross CrossVersion.fullMapped{
      _ => scalaVersionSelect
    }
  )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CrossVersion.fullMapped` wasn't kept in its sbt 0.13 form because sbt 1.x wanted to be able to serialize its key types (and `CrossVersion` is a transitive part of that object graph).

It was replaced by `CrossVersion.fullWith`, which instead of taking a general `String => String` function takes a `String` prefix and a `String` suffix to prepend/append to the Scala binary version.

But given you're discarding the input to use `scalaVersionSelect` then you don't even need `CrossVersion.fullWith` and can just use `CrossVersion.constant`, as in:

```
addCompilerPlugin(
  "org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.1"
    cross CrossVersion.constant(scalaVersionSelect)
)
```